# Trying to cancel existing http request with new one using switchMap in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic3, switchmap

My goal is to use RxJs `switchMap` in an Ionic 3 project, to cancel any ongoing login attempts if a server is offline, and use latest request only. Otherwise I can get some unwanted asynchronous side effects later.

In my view layer, I'm using `submitStream$` to capture a button clickstream, then passing that to the service layer as a method argument.
In the service layer, I'm creating `response$` via a `switchMap`, combining, the passed parameter `submitStream$`, with an `Observable<Response>` that comes back from `this.webServiceUtil.testLogin()`.

I tried implementing this code:

**HTML markup**

```
<button #submit type="submit">Submit</button>
```

**Typescript : View Layer**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
export class LoginPage {
  @ViewChild('submit') button: ElementRef
  submitStream$:any;
  ...
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.submitStream$ = 
    Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
  }
  ...
}
```

**Typescript : Service Layer (submitStream$ comes in as method argument)**

```
this.response$ = submitStream$.switchMap(click =>
    this.webServiceUtil.testLogin())
```

I've also tried creating `this.submitStream$` in `ngAfterViewInit()`

When things didn't work I also tried appending this to the Observable.fromEvent:

```
 .subscribe(ev => {
    console.log('LoginPage: ionViewDidLoad() submitStream$.subscribe(): ev:', ev);}
  )
```

How do I overcome the **'[ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/FromEventObservable.ts#L143)'**?

Comment: Why are you using switchMap() ?

Comment: Try to move this code to  ngAfterViewInit() function

Comment: @SandeepSharma to be able to cancel iniital http request and accept latest only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have to do some funky stuff to make what you subscribe to, look correct in RxJs's eyes...

So this is what I did to solve the ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target:

```
  @ViewChild('submit') button: any;

    this.submitClickStream$ = 
      Observable.fromEvent(this.button._elementRef.nativeElement  , 'click')
      .subscribe(ev => {
        console.log('ev: ', ev);},
        (err) => {console.error(err);}
      );
```

In **AuthService**, passing either the `submitClickStream$`, or the button element from @ViewChild, and doing Observable.fromEvent on it from within AuthService, I was unable to get the subscribe with the console logging of events, to ever fire.

So, I introduced a BehaviourSubject intermediary.

I could just use regular `(click)='onSubmit()'` again in the `<button>` element of **LoginPage.html**.

In the onSubmit() method of **LoginPage.ts**, I could directly use the BehaviourSubject with `this.clickStream$.next('');`.

This did away with the complexities of Observable.fromEvent, and ViewChild.

switchMap finally worked, cancelling earlier ongoing requests without messy unsubscribe logic.

**LoginPage.ts**

```
import { BehaviorSubject }     from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { AuthService }         from './../../providers/auth-service';
import { LoginCredentials }    from './../../model/loginCredentials';
export class LoginPage {

  private clickStream$:BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor(
   private authService:AuthService,
  ) {
     this.clickStream$ = new BehaviorSubject('');
  }

  onSubmit():void {
    console.log('LoginPage: onSumbit()');
    this.clickStream$.next('');
    this.authService
      .login(this.prepareCredentials(), 
             this.clickStream$
            );
  }

}
```

**AuthService**

```
import { BehaviorSubject }      from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { LoginCredentials }     from './../../model/loginCredentials';
import { WebServiceUtil }       from './web-service-util';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

 login(
    loginCredentials: LoginCredentials, 
    clickStream$: BehaviorSubject<any>
  ) {
     this.response$ = clickStream$.switchMap(click =>  {
                      console.log('AuthService: login() : click: ', click);
                      return this.webServiceUtil.testLogin();
                                                       }
                                            );
     this.response$.subscribe(
         (response:Response) => {....},
          (err) => {console.error(err); ....}

  }
}
```

**WebServiceUtil**

```
@Injectable()
export class WebServiceUtil {

  testLogin(
  ): Observable<Response> {
  ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Please use switch map as given below. Hope this help!

```
this.submitStream$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.button._elementRef.nativeElement, 'click');

this.submitStream$
      .switchMap(click => {
        return this.dummyAPIResponse(); // this should return observalbe(i.e new observalbe)...
      })
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });


dummyAPIResponse(){
 return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next([1, 2, 3, 4]);
      }, 10000);
    });
}
```